# nginx:alpine config not correctly work with dockerimage

Tags: angularjs, docker, angular-ui-router, docker-desktop

I want to host my angular app in my local browser.

[image]

This is my docker file configuration:-

```
FROM node:10.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . ./
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now I try to build image and run it on localhost:8080 :-

PS C:\github_programming\ASP.NET and Angular\QuizQuestion\Fornted> docker run --name quizquestion1 -d -p 8080:80 quizequstion
005fd1a397f38c54675b24be1a502b32edadc5f653bcda8bee07b62c4448b3a7

I am only able to see only nginx welcome page.

[image]

If I browse http://localhost:8080/quiz:-

[image]

But it is working with  npm start:-

[image]

I have little confused what I have missed here.

I do this exercise after I get a suggestion from Mr.Dave Maze
[image]

It shows lots of unwanted folder.So, I change the following in my docker file:-

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

now folder structure like that:-
[image]

But it doesn't work, I am not getting desired result.
http://localhost:4000/quiz
PS C:\github_programming\ASP.NET and Angular\QuizQuestion\Fornted>

Docker run command:-

```
docker run --name quizquestion4 -d -p 4000:80 quizequstion
```

22ac476a121d221808415a2f59c6f511e765fd7d5325c03b9ff320905e0cd02c.
yup it working fine without docker.

Things I have noticed:-
If I have changed the app-routing.modules like that:-`

```
{ path: '', component: QuizComponent},
{ path: 'quiz', component: QuizComponent},
{ path: 'question', component: QuestionComponent },
{ path: 'question/:quizId', component: QuestionComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},    
{ path: 'customer-list', component: CustomerListComponent},
```

Then I create new docker image and rebuild it.
I run it on port on http://localhost:4001:- I can see the quiz form

[image]

But routing http://localhost:4001/quiz doesn't work. It gives me 404 not found.

Yes locally, without dockerimage it is working:-
[image]

So for angular routing do I need to do any additions things to make docker image.

I tag angular js for that.

I think I missed something in docker build.

Any suggestion regarding this.
Thank you

Comment: If you `docker run --rm quizequstion ls /usr/share/nginx/html` to see what's in the image, is it your built application, or something else?  (Do you need to `COPY /usr/src/app/build` into the final image, rather than the entire `/usr/src/app` tree?)

Comment: Hi David, I follow your instruction. Change the command like that:-                                       FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html.But still not getting the desired result. I have updated  the question

Comment: I create ./dist folder using npm run build --prod and run this commands.                                                                         1. npm install -g http-server
2. http-server ./dist..............still I get the same error.So it is not working on local http-server as well.Now I got confused.Have I create dist folder correctly.

Answer (score 0):

for docker container if you did not specific any host it will launch on the docker container ip.

you can get this by (below) and get the IPAddress (lots of other good info there too!)

`docker inspect <container id>`

if you just want the IPAddress:

```
docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"
```

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

> By default, the container is assigned an IP address for every Docker
> network it connects to. The IP address is assigned from the pool
> assigned to the network, so the Docker daemon effectively acts as a
> DHCP server for each container. Each network also has a default subnet
> mask and gateway.

Comment: Yup...."Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            },

Comment: I am browsing with 8080 :-localhost:8080..I think there is any other problem.

Comment: ? there should be one for "IPAddress" .. It is not there? No IPAddress?

Comment: "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
  "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",

Comment: yes do 172.17.0.2

Comment: Like that:- http://172.17.0.2/quiz

Comment: This site can’t be reached....I get this error

Comment: hey your docker port is 80 u bind 8080 to 80..

Comment: can you ping 172.17.0.2 logically everything is inplace...
 172.17.0.2:80/quiz .. @SangitaPaul

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246482/discussion-between-invertedowlcoding-and-sangita-paul).

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address is all but useless: it doesn't work on MacOS hosts, or Windows hosts, or if you're not on the same host as the container.  In all of these contexts use can use a `docker run -p` published port without knowing the container's Docker-internal IP address, and you never need to look it up.

Comment: thats good to note dave, i have only really used ubuntu .. so .. however, Paul had used docker run -p but was not able to get the results? what is the issue here then?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:-

So, I change the dockerfile content:-

```
FROM node:10.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . ./
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build --prod

# FROM nginx:alpine
# COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# EXPOSE 80
# CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]



FROM nginx:1.15.8
EXPOSE 80
COPY conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Also we need to create Nginx configuration file in the project folder.

like that:-

[image]

Code for configuration file:-

```
server {
listen 80;
sendfile on;
default_type application/octet-stream;
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_min_length   1100;
gzip_vary         on;
gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json 
application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml 
application/xml+rss text/javascript;
gzip_comp_level   9;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
}
```

See help :- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-10-on-docker-to-production-61ee6e84006

Thanks to all contributor for this post